# Perl6: Match elements in a list with another list

Tags: raku

I have a list of numbers **L**. There is another list of numbers **M**. I need to return a list **L'** of numbers found in *both* **L** and **M**.

***Edit***: Mathematically, I am looking for [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) intersection.

Example:

> **L**  = 3, `1`, 4, `1`, 5, `9`, `2`, 6
>   **M**  = `9`, 7, `1`, `2`, `1`, 1
>   **L'** = 9, 1, 2, 1

I wrote the [following code](https://glot.io/snippets/eoidoekxwl) for that:

```
my @some-numbers = 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6;
my @to-match     = 9, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1;
my @matched;

my %histogram;
for @some-numbers -> $n { %histogram{$n}++ };

for @to-match -> $n {
    next if not defined %histogram{$n};
    if %histogram{$n} > 0 {
        push @matched, $n;
        %histogram{$n}--;
    }
};

say @matched;
```

While it achieves the purpose, I was wondering whether there was an *idiomatic* Perl6 way of doing this?

Some background: I have been trying to learn Perl6 and Python together, and solve the same puzzles in both the languages. Python offered a particularly [pleasing solution](https://glot.io/snippets/eoidps68u7) for the above problem. To my beginner eyes at least :)

Comment: Why is there two, and not three occurences of `1` in `L'`?

Comment: In Perl5 you can do `my %seen  = map { $_ => 1 } @to_match; my @match = grep { exists $seen{$_} } @some_numbers`

Comment: Sorry for not being precise in framing the question. I realized now that what I was looking for was [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) intersection. I've edited the problem statement to reflect that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the precise semantics you're looking for, [Bag](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Bag) operations might be just the ticket:

```
my \L = 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6;
my \M = 9, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1;

.put with L.Bag ∩ M.Bag;
```

displays:

```
9 1(2) 2
```

This is the stringification of a `Bag` containing the three *keys* `'9'`, `'1'`, and `'2'` whose respective *values* (repeat counts) are the integers `1`, `2`, and `1`.

To get Perl 6 to produce a list from a bag with each key repeated the number of times indicated by its associated value, use the `.kxxv` method:

```
.kxxv.put with L.Bag ∩ M.Bag;
```

displays:

```
9 1 1 2
```

(The mnemonic for the `kxxv` method is that it's `k` for "key" then `xx` in analogy with the [`xx`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/xx) repetition operator and finally `v` for "value". It sorta makes sense if you think about it.)

But perhaps a bag won't do. For example, perhaps the order of elements in the result matters -- you need `9 1 2 1` and not `9 1 1 2`? I'll extend this answer if a bag isn't the right way to go.

Comment: If "9 1 2" would be an acceptable answer, you don't actually need to coerce to Bag first, you can just take the intersection of the two lists: "L (&) M" (using the Texas version of ∩).  The intersection uses Set semantics by default.

Comment: Bags do it perfectly for me! The order of elements returned from the intersection does not matter.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with bags:

```
my $some-numbers = bag 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6;
my $to-match     = bag 9, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1;
my $matched      = $some-numbers ∩ $to-match;
say $matched;
```

**Output:**

```
bag(9, 1(2), 2)
```

You can turn the bag back into an array with `.kxxv`.

```
my @match-list = $matched.kxxv;
say @match-list;
```

**Output:**

```
[9 1 1 2]
```

(If you don't care about duplicates, use sets instead of bags.)

Comment: for anyone having trouble with Unicode operators, the Texas version of `∩` is `(&)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
use v6;

my @some_numbers = 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6;
my @to_match     = 9, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1;
my %seen  = map { $_ => 1 }, @to_match;
my @matched = grep { %seen{$_}:exists }, @some_numbers;
say @matched;
```

**Output**:

```
[1 1 9 2]
```

Comment: Kinda Perl5ish looking..  
You could use `@to_match X=> 1;` to build the `%seen` hash instead of the map,
or just forgo the %seen hash entirely and use `@some_numbers.grep: { @to_match.first($_) };`

Comment: Doesn't work right if extra elements in first list: `@some_numbers = 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 1; @to_match     = 9, 7, 1, 2, 1`